# What is wrong with this code?

Tags: 7, nodes

I am having a slight problem with my code; I am trying to do a if statement to make the date not print if a node is using a certain term. I have parsed `$node` to narrow down what term I would like to exclude the date from being used.

This is what is returned in the dump:

```
Array ([und] => Array ([0] => Array ([tid] => 103 )))
```

This is what I have for my code to have the date being displayed:

```
      if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
        $node = node_load(arg(1));
        $user = user_load(array('uid' => $node->uid));
        foreach ($node->field_newsections['und']['0'] as $node_time);
      }

      hide($content['comments']);
      hide($content['links']);
      $nodecontent = render($content);
      $newcontent = preg_replace("/<p[^>]*?>/", "", $nodecontent);
      $newcontent = str_replace("</p>", "<br /><br />", $newcontent);

      if ($node->type == 'post' || 'news') {
        echo '<div id="date-created">'. date('l, F j, Y g:ia', $node->created). '</div>';
      }
      else ($node_time == '108') {
        echo 'working';
      }

      print render($newcontent);
```

I am probably over looking something small.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three things that needs to be corrected, in your code.

- You are using a `foreach` statement without any block; this means that that control statement is not doing anything.

  ```
  foreach ($node->field_newsections['und']['0'] as $node_time);
  ```
- You are using an `else` statement followed by a condition; or you use an `else` statement without condition, or you really meant to use the `elseif` statement.

  ```
  else ($node_time == '108') {
    //...
  }
  ```
- You are using `render()` with `$newcontent`, which is set with a previous call to `render()`.

  ```
  $nodecontent = render($content);
  $newcontent = preg_replace("/<p[^>]*?>/", "", $nodecontent);
  $newcontent = str_replace("</p>", "<br /><br />", $newcontent);
  ```

  While `render()`, which returns a string, checks when the parameter it gets is a string, instead of an array, and it returns that parameter immediately, it is useless to call `render()` with the result of a previous call to `render()`, even if that string has been modified from any function to alter a string.

Also, as you said (in a comment for this answer) that you are using that code inside the "node.tpl.php" template file, that template file has already access to the `$node`variable that contains the node object for the node being shown. As the template file is only used for nodes, the following code is useless:

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
  $user = user_load(array('uid' => $node->uid));
  // …
}
```

It is also unusual for a theme replacing the HTML content; that is normally done in a module.

Supposing that you are trying to use the last item in the `$node->field_newsections['und']['0']` array (which seems a term array), I would rather use the following code:

```
$tid = array_pop($node->field_newsections['und']);
$node_time = $tid['tid'];

hide($content['comments']);
hide($content['links']);
$nodecontent = render($content);
$newcontent = preg_replace("/<p[^>]*?>/", "", $nodecontent);
$newcontent = str_replace("</p>", "<br /><br />", $newcontent);

if ($node_time != '103') {
  print '<div id="date-created">'. date('l, F j, Y g:ia', $node->created). '</div>';
}

print $newcontent;
```

Comment: im using this inside of my theme inside of my node.tpl.php file and the else condition was a typo, i corrected the code now

Comment: im ot trying to use the code inside a block it works fine inside the template file however I just want to exclude the date from being displayed on any nodes using term 103

Comment: If you are using it inside node.tpl.php, then you are not using it inside a block. By the way, where are you outputting a block?

Comment: @kiamlaluno.  +1 LIke I said before, You should write a book!